# List unchanged files in default changelist with P4 command line

Tags: perforce

Is there a way to list all unchanged files from default pending changelist with P4 command line tool? For some reason I would like to detect such files and make further changes. Thanks a lot.

Best Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`p4 revert`](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r12.1/manuals/cmdref/revert.html).

Saying

```
p4 revert -a
```

would **revert** all unchanged files.

You don't want to revert but want to list the unchanged files, so supply the `-n` option.  Saying:

```
p4 revert -a -n
```

would **list** the unchanged files *without* performing any action.